# Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-platform

I get the following error when using the google cloud stt sample app on my

Android studio: The app itself has already been compiled and run in another

Android studio environment.

**Compile Error**

```
Program type already present:com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder
$LimitedInputStreamMessage{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream, 
sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My os is ubuntu 16.04 and Android version is Android studio V 3.1. Below
It is a gradle source.

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

   ext {
grpcVersion = '1.4.0'
  }
   android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.androidkt.speechapi"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    multiDexEnabled  true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'

    }
}
protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0'
}
plugins {
    javalite {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
    }
    grpc {
        artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        task.plugins {
            javalite {}
            grpc {
                // Options added to --grpc_out
                option 'lite'
             }
         }
     }
   }
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'

// gRPC
compile "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.3.1'

compile group: 'com.google.api.grpc', name: 'grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1', version: '0.1.13'

// OAuth2 for Google API
compile('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Of gradle source

```
compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
```

Commenting this part will not cause an error. The errors related to protobuffer and grpc, but it is difficult to solve correctly.

I need help.

Comment: Is there any chance that your app is depending on both com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite and com.google.protobuf:protobuf? I believe mixing the two will lead to problems. You can see the full list of dependencies by running "./gradlew :app:dependencies"

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Any leads on this??

Comment: @Swapnil - Could you solve this

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and it can be **temporarily** solved by disabling [D8](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8) tool by setting Gradle property in `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableD8=false
```

I am using Android Studio 3.2 RC2.